# Access Check for Blank, Null or Empty Fields

Tags: loops, ms-access, null, vba, is-empty

I have a form that has dozens of fields on it.

The fields are a combination of Text boxes and Combo boxes. I'm trying to figure out a single button solution to check for empty/blank/null fields.

If a blank is found, I would like it show a form; if none are found, I would like it close the current form.

My code is below.

It successfully loops through all the fields and shows a form when it finds a blank/empty/null field, but I can't figure out how to close the form if (and only if) there are no blank/empty/null fields on the form.

```vb
Private Sub Command146_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control

    With Me
        For Each ctl In .Controls
            If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
                If Len(ctl.Value & "") = 0 Then
                    DoCmd.OpenForm "PopMissingData"
                    Exit For
                End If ' Value
            End If ' ControlType
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a counter to your code with initial value 0. Add 1 to the counter for each empty/null/blank control. If counter > 0 -> open your PopMissingData form. Else, close the current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the Control object has "run out":

```
Private Sub Command146_Click()

    Dim ctl As Control

    With Me
        For Each ctl In .Controls
            If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
                If Len(ctl.Value & "") = 0 Then
                    Exit For
                End If ' Value
            End If ' ControlType
        Next
    End With

    If ctl Is Nothing Then
        ' All controls validated.
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    Else
        ' Open the other form.
        ' ctl will hold the non-validated control.
        DoCmd.OpenForm "PopMissingData"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Aren't you missing something? `ctl` never is `Nothing` if there exists at least one control on the form.

Comment: @UnhandledException: Nope - easy to check out.

Comment: You are right, the `For Each` loop will set `ctl` to `Nothing` at the end. I missed that.